# update datatable inside a dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to know how to update a Datatable which is inside a dataset.I have a datatable in which i have details of some item.Now i want to add this into a dataset for some purpose and update it.Give me some suggesions to solve this..

this is my code:

```
                DataRow dr;
                dr = Basket_DataTable.NewRow();
                Basket_DataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
                dr["PId"] = getPId.ToString();
                dr["ProductName"] = getProductName.ToString();
                dr["ImagePath"] = getImagePath.ToString();
                dr["ProductPrice"] = getProductPrice.ToString();
                dr["Quantity"] = getQuantity.ToString();
                dr["ProductDescription"] = getProductDescription.ToString();
                dr["TotalPrice"] = getProductPrice.ToString();
                Basket_DataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Basket_DataTable is my datatable which i need to add to a dataset and update..

Comment: Don't call `AcceptChanges` if you want to commit changes to database. Use a `DataAdapter` to [update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update.aspx) the database.

Comment: _"how to update a Datatable which is inside a dataset"_  and then _"i want to add this into a dataset"_. What's the question actually?

Comment: @TimSchmelter:i want to add and then update ..

Comment: If it's _inside_ a `DataSet`, why do you need to add it? Is it an strongly typed DataSet created via designer or a loosely typed created manually? Anyway, have you tried `dataSet.Tables.Add`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to add new Rows to your existing DataTable in your DataSet. Instead of creating a new DataTable, your `Basket_DataTable` should refer to your data table in the data set.

Something like.

```
//Create new Row from your DataTable in DataSet
DataRow dr = yourDataSet.Tables["Basket_DataTable"].NewRow();
// here you can refer to your datatable with the index as well 
//e.g. yourDataSet.Tables[0]

Basket_DataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
dr["PId"] = getPId.ToString();
dr["ProductName"] = getProductName.ToString();
dr["ImagePath"] = getImagePath.ToString();
dr["ProductPrice"] = getProductPrice.ToString();
dr["Quantity"] = getQuantity.ToString();
dr["ProductDescription"] = getProductDescription.ToString();
dr["TotalPrice"] = getProductPrice.ToString();

//Remember to add your row to the table. 
yourDataSet.Tables["Basket_DataTable"].Rows.Add(dr);
```

In your current code you are not adding the new row to the datatable. Remember to include the row in the datatable.

Comment: if i add it is not updating.it is giving me a error "datatable already in dataset".

Comment: :yes i have added the datatable to dataset,i want to update the  new row of  Basket_DataTable in the dataset..

Comment: @Masterbrain,  You are not adding the row to the datatable. Does my edit works for you ?

Comment: first time its working fine.but after t hat its giving me the same error "DataTable already belongs to another DataSet."

Comment: @Masterbrain, are you trying to add that DataTable to some new dataSet if so you may try `DataTable.Clone()`

Answer (score 0):

If the DataTable is already in an existing DataSet, but you want to add it to another one, you need to create a copy first - A DataTable instance can only have one parent DataSet.

```
DataTable Basket_DataTable_copy = Basket_DataTable.Copy();
yourDataSet.Tables.Add(Basket_DataTable_copy);
```

Then you can do your updates on Basket_DataTable_copy

see [DataTable.Copy on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx)